# Acquia - Get task context in web hook

Tags: drupal, webhooks, acquia

What I want is to know if it is possible to get the "task" details in the web hook sripts, post a deployment job in Acquia cloud.

Let me explain a bit more. In the [post-code-update](https://github.com/acquia/cloud-hooks#post-code-update) hook, maybe I want to know what is the task that is running currently for which the hook has been triggered. Like the task id, the task name, time it started, time it ended etc. Actually I am trying to automate something based on this details.

Help appreciated.